# Cannot create a string longer than 0x3fffffe7 characters

Tags: javascript

I'm using Request library (gzip enabled) and it crash with this error.

It seems this error occur at this line,

```
response.body = response.body.toString(self.encoding)
```

Scope containing that line,

```
response.body = Buffer.concat(buffers, bufferLength)
if (self.encoding !== null) {
 response.body = response.body.toString(self.encoding)
}
```

Full Stacktrace,

```
Error: Cannot create a string longer than 0x3fffffe7 characters
    at Buffer.utf8Slice (<anonymous>)
    at Buffer.toString (buffer.js:797:17)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/home/proj/node_modules/request/request.js:1128:39)
    at Request.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/proj/node_modules/request/request.js:1076:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:421:28)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1220:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  code: 'ERR_STRING_TOO_LONG'
}
```

What's the best way to convert the buffer to String when it's longer than 1073741799 characters?

Comment: That's within the ballpark of the length of Tolstoy's *War and Peace*. What exactly are we talkin bout here? Why are you trying to create a 1~2 MB string?

Comment: Javascript isn't equipped to really handle strings of that size. The error could not be clearer, actually. This is not the tool for the job.

Comment: @JaredSmith I don't but the request library does. I fetch websites you know and that size is common but it unable to move forward.

Comment: @somethinghere It's NodeJS. It should be able to handle strings of that size.

Comment: But I'm open to skipping this string as-well. I just don't know what should I do to skip it.

Comment: NodeJS = Javascript, I don't know why I need to point this out. The error you described is clear, concise, and points at the problem. Turns out, you are using the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: @somethinghere No. It's right tool for web crawling. It seems it somehow fetch a binary file instead HTML.  I will put together an answer soon. It seems NodeJS has a limit of  1GB for buffer.toString

Comment: @somethinghere I was under impression that it's an actually a HTML file hence the ignorance

Comment: It is an HTML file, a buffer is just the binary representation of the contents of said file.

Comment: @somethinghere I knew what Buffer means. The size is over 2GB and it's not an HTML file. It's a trap or something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems I ran into a [crawling trap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider_trap) while crawling the websites. The page that request fetched is almost over 2GB in size.

NodeJS's `Buffer.toString` has a limit of 1 GB and this content is way over that.

The authors of request library has forgotten to put a catch block inside the toString operation.

The fix is to add the catch block like below in `request.js` file's line 1130,

```
  if (self.encoding !== null) {
    try {
      response.body = response.body.toString(self.encoding)
    } catch(e) {
      self.emit('error', e)
    }
  }
```

Comment: your question was "What's the best way to convert the buffer to String when it's longer than 1073741799 characters?", and this answer does not answer the question...

Comment: @OhadR I am bad with numbers due to dyslexia. I thought 1073741799  chars small amount at that time not something like 2GB.

Comment: true, but adding a catch block still does not help u to convert a big string... am I wrong?